# Apple Airport and Ubuntu Compatibility

Tags: wireless

This is my first time using the forum. I have an old Mac Pro from 2007 running Lion. It's software is no longer supported and the hardware isn't compatible with later versions of OS X so I am planning to format the HD and install Ubuntu.

So here's the question. The old Mac was not manufactured with a wifi card installed. I have wifi on it using an airport express that extends the wifi from our home. I have the airport plugged into the computer using Ethernet.

If I erase the OS X and install Ubuntu, will the airport still work through Ethernet? I assume it will, but am not sure since I won't have airport utility.

Comment: You could always boot from a Live USB and try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Without Airport Utility you will no longer be able to change the configuration on the Airport Express, but it will keep working with its current configuration. It doesn't matter at all to the functionality of the Airport Express whether you're running Linux or OS X, except when you want to change its config.